# Best way to dynamically update jQuery UI attribute with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an attribute in which I add the "draggable" directive to. This enables the jQuery UI draggable component. My directive is as follows:

```
  testModule.directive('draggable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({ revert: true });
      }
    }
  });
```

I have a scope function which checks whether or not these items should be enabled/disabled. I am using the ng-class directive to add/remove a disabled class. It looks as follows (it obviously does other things but for simplicity I just return false):

```
$scope.enabled = function(){
  return false;
}
```

So to get my disabled class applied I can do something like:

```
<span draggable data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-class="{disabled: enabled()}">{{item.Name}}</span>
```

My question is that if I want to do something simliar and when enabled returns false, what is the best way to do this. I looked at using $watch, however it isn't necesarilly dependent on an item changing but rather on the state of the application, which combines multiple factors. All I want is something simple that says if enabled returns false grab the element with and use jQuery to disable draggable like so - $(element).draggable("disable")

I feel like there should be a straightforward way to do this but I cannot seem to get a directive to function properly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the state of the item to the `draggable` directive you already have created.

HTML:

```
<div draggable="item.enabled" data-ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{disabled: !item.enabled }">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//in your controller
$scope.items = [{ name:'item1', enabled: false}, { name:'item2', enabled: true}, { name:'item3', enabled: true}, { name:'item4', enabled: false}, { name:'item5', enabled: true}];

app.directive('draggable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).draggable({ revert: true, disabled: !scope.$eval(attrs.draggable) });
      }
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/aZosUrE/4/

Comment: Thanks! One more question, if enabled is a function and can change throughout the application, is that a problem? I thought the link function only executed the first time the item is generated.

Comment: Also for clarification each item does not have an enabled property. Enabled is a function which looks at multiple aspects of the application to determine whether or not that draggable should be enabled. It isn't just a simple attribute.